# Questions on differential equations of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $$N'_x(x)=G(x)N(x)$$ where $N, G$ are $2\times2$ matrices depending on $x$, and $G$ satisfies $\sigma G+G\sigma=0$, $\sigma$ is one half of the pauli matrix, i.e. $$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$ My question is:

> Would $N^{\ast}\sigma N$ then be independent of $x$? Why or why not?

Comment: Is $N'_x(x)$ the derivative of $N(x)$ wrt $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that $N^\prime(x) = G(x)N(x)$, it follows by linearity of the operator $A \mapsto A^\ast$ that  $$(N^\ast)^\prime(x) = (N^\prime(x))^\ast = (G(x)N(x))^\ast = N(x)^\ast G(x)^\ast.$$
Hence, by the noncommutative Leibniz rule,
$$
 (N(x)^\ast\sigma N(x))^\prime = (N(x))^\ast \sigma N(x) + N(x)^\ast \sigma^\prime N(x) + N(x)^\ast \sigma N(x)^\prime\\ = N(x)^\ast G(x)^\ast \sigma N(x) + N^\ast(x) \sigma G(x) N(x)\\ = N(x)^\ast\left(G(x)^\ast - G(x)\right)\sigma N(x).
$$
What can you conclude from this? In particular, what would be a convenient condition to impose on $G$ to guarantee that $(N(x)^\ast\sigma N(x))^\prime=0$?